# Why does function from $\mathbb Z \to \mathbb Z$, $n\mapsto 2n$ is not surjective?

Tags: functions

Can anyone explain why the following function is not surjective?

$$\mathbb Z \to \mathbb Z$$

$$n\mapsto 2n$$

Comment: Which $n$ maps to $1$?

Comment: Carefully read the definition of "surjective" and try to apply it here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because in co-domain, none of the odd integers was mapped with an integer in domain.